# OOP using pygame.display inheritance error

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

```
import pygame.display.Display as display


class MainDisplay(display):

    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()

        # creating display
        X = 500
        Y = 1000

        display = self.set_mode((X, Y))
```

The following code is giving this type error:

```
module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Is this because pygame.display is a module not a class? How could I fix this error?

edit:
this is the full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/siyunlee/Desktop/coding/personal/games/dino game/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    class MainDisplay(display):
TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of how to make a window I recommend using this:

```py
import pygame

class MainDisplay():

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.display.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

MainDisplay()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

Comment: thank you for the solution, but do you mind explaining why my first code gave the error? Just very curious

Comment: @SiyunLee try this